# How to restore accidentally deleted Chrome Profile on Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I had a few Person 1,2,3 profiles in Chrome and 1 of them had a bunch of super useful extensions, history, passwords, etc. After I deleted them, I lost all of my Chrome data. Is there a way to restore Chrome Profile from a few hours ago? You know what I mean by Profiles? [image]

Comment: If the profile wasn't synced to a Google account, then no — at least, not easily; Chrome doesn't provide an "undelete profile" feature, and the files you need are now deleted, so data recovery software must be used to get them back if you're really desperate for them, and the process will be very tedious indeed

Comment: Thank you. Pain in the ass then. I haven't backed up for a couple of months because Time Machine slows down my mac. Yes, it was under Google account. But I can't still find the way to restore it. This is so lame of Google to let you create profile, delete it, but not restore. Isn't a basic user expectation to restore something in case you accidentally deleted it?

Comment: TM should not normally slow down your Mac, so that's worth having a look at and getting fixed.
Backups are essential for exactly this kind of thing: apps don't tend to provide another mechanism.